# Get Application context URL in SimpleMappingExceptionResolver

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception

I use `SimpleMappingExceptionResolver` to redirect to URIs in case of some my custom exceptions.

The problem with this is the redirect does not honor the application context ( which i easily get in JSP using `<c:url value="/" />`).
The problem is how do i get it in Spring configuration XML

context.xml -

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver" p:defaultErrorView="errorView">
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
        <props>
            <prop key=".MyCustomException">redirect:/error</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="exceptionAttribute"><null/></property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a better way of doing this.

Declare your `SimpleMappingExceptionResolver` like this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver"> 
<property name="exceptionMappings">
    <props>
        <prop key="com.example.MyCustomException">error</prop>
    </props>
</property>
</bean>
```

This will configure Spring MVC to redirect the client to a error view whenever an `MyCustomException` is thrown.

Then, you configure the `ViewResolver` like this:

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

So, it will look for the "/WEB-INF/views/error.jsp" page to render. You won't need the url or anything. Spring will take care of everything.

Reference: http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/how-to-handle-exceptions-in-spring-mvc

Comment: Though I am using this in some cases, but not in all cases. As in some cases i need to call redirect so that appropriate interceptor stacks are called and i can modify the response ( headers etc.)

Comment: Could you post some code snippets showing this case?